# How to programmatically install a jar file to startup on all operating systems - Java

Tags: java, service, registry

So i have come across a problem with installing my java application to startup on all Operating Systems.

Firstly I know this is possible on **Windows** by adding a new key to registry (I think).

```
I believe the command: 'reg add' works on windows.
```

I'm not 100% sure about **Mac** but i believe you can use a service wrapper?

And for **Linux** I have no clue.

Basically i want my application to be installed to startup when a user ticks a box, no matter which operating system it is run on.

Just some clarification on these and if possible an example for each would really assist me.
Any help with this is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: By "on startup", do you mean as a system service(when the computer boots), or as a user application (when the user log in)?

Comment: I mean when the computer logs in, it will execute the file.

Comment: You haven't clearly answered my question.  Do you mean that the program should run when the computer starts (whether or not any user has logged in; so call it a "daemoon", not an "application")? Or that it should run when the user who "installed" it log in again? Or that it should run when any user logs in?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, i want it to be executed when any user on the computer logs in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.desktop` file to one of the following directories:

- `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/autostart/` (`/etc/xdg/autostart/` by default) for all users
- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart/` (`~/.config/autostart/` by default) for a particular user

See the [FreeDesktop.org Desktop Application Autostart Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) for details.

So for example,

```
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(
        System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.config/autostart/myapp.desktop"));
    out.println("[Desktop Entry]");
    out.println("Name=myapp");
    out.println("Comment=Autostart entry for myapp");
    out.println("Exec=" + installPath + "/bin/myapp_wrapper.sh");
    out.println("Icon=" + installPath + "/myapp_icon.png");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Comment: Linux. For Windows, maybe see http://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd .  For MacOS, maybe see http://www.coderanch.com/t/111733/Mac/create-alias-Mac-java or http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2010/Feb/msg00091.html .